# Chained selects with where at the end

Tags: c#, linq

Given following structure: a person has functions. Each function has roles. Each roles has features. Now I would like to figure out with linq if a given person has a certain feature, but I am doing something wrong with this query. As a result I always get the count of the functions (but I'd like to get the count of the features):

```
var count = person.Functions
                  .Select(fu => fu.Roles
                                  .Select(r => r.Features
                                                .Where(f => f.FeatureId == 99999)))
                  .Count();
```

What am I doing wrong here? According to this query I expect either 0 (hasn't got the feature) or 1.

Comment: Is this VB.net or C#? I'm confused, looks like a mixture to me.

Comment: i think _ is ), just pressed wrong key

Comment: @Reniuz, even then its not proper C#. A lamdba looks compleltey different.

Comment: It was VB, tried to fix that, should look better now.

Comment: @Steven oh...i missed that :)

Comment: @sl3dg3, you need to use == in C# for comparisons.

Comment: You are not chaining but nesting. If you want to explore what is actually happening then try to assign the value of the query before the Count to a variable. Try writing the type of the variable (Ie don't use 'var') The type is not what you expect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query = from function in person.Functions
            from role in function.Roles
            from feature in role.Features
            where feature.FeatureId == 99999
            select feature;

var count = query.Count();
```

or

```
var count = person.Functions
                  .SelectMany(function => function.Roles)
                  .SelectMany(role => role.Features)
                  .Count(feature => feature.FeatureId == 99999);
```

If you don't need the exact count but just want to know if the person has the feature or not, use [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx)  instead of [`Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx).

Comment: Right, `Any` would do the job in my case!

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = person.Functions
             .SelectMany(p => p.Roles)
             .SelectMany(r => r.Features)
             .Where(f => f.FeatureId == 99999)
             .Count();
```

I'm not really sure, but I think you want the total number of Features with teh given Id. You would want to use SelectMany.